# CI in GIT: how to revert multiple commits of a feature

Tags: git, continuous-integration

During continuous integration, we merge all feature branches to develop branch at least once a day; and pull mainline to feature branches also at least daily. There might be many commits, since feature/integration branch can be updated daily.

Then it appears that feature X is not going to be released. How to revert all commits, related to feature X, from develop?

After such revert, teams, working with all other feature branches, will pull in master branch (so that feature A code will be eliminated from them as well). Could this be done in usual way; or should any special steps be taken?

UPDATE: experience shows that on the day, when we attempt to carefully merge wanted features, we have huge merge conflicts; moreover, testing needs to start from ground zero. Our plan is to avoid this by merging into develop, and pulling from develop into feature branches, daily. On the cut off day we may decide that some feature is not making it into release, and, therefore, need to rollback this feature. Looking for specific advice for GIT command for this specific situation : how to "rollback all commits by feature name". Thank you!

Comment: Your master branch should be either a development branch or a stable/release branch. Not both. Pick one workflow and stick to it.

Comment: This workflow is like asking for trouble... anyway how many commits you might have to rollback?

Comment: there may be multiple commits; the plan is to do continuous integration, to avoid huge merge conflicts eventually. Need to find a way to rollback en-masse, something like "rollback all commits for feature A"

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb, if you are having to rollback things then you are probably doing something wrong.

In my opinion your CI branch - the one that is downloaded built and tested by your CI scripts - should be separate from your release/stable branch. Having said this you can either develop and merge in master and have a dedicated release branch, or vice versa. Either approach has ups and downs so it's up to you to pick which one suits you best.

The day you are finally ready to package a release you would then carefully merge the wanted features and build and test that release branch.

Comment: thank you for sharing; however, experience shows that on the day, when we attempt to carefully merge wanted features, we experience huge merge conflicts; moreover, testing needs to start from ground zero. Our plan is to avoid this by merging into develop, and pulling from develop into feature branches, daily. On the cut off day we may decide that some feature is not making it into release, and, therefore, need to rollback this feature. Looking for specific advice for GIT command for this specific situation : how to "rollback all commits by feature name". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can launch deactivated features in production using the feature toggles concept. In the next development cycle, you can either complete it or create a task to remove it